# Convert dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe and i want it to select a few columns and convert it into Dictionary in the a certain manner

Dataframe:

[image: Dataframe :]

and here's the output I want

```
{20: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 20],
21: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 21],
 22: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0, 22],
 23: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 23]}
```

I have tried this

```
items_dic = data[["Length","Width","Height","Pid" ]].set_index('Pid').T.to_dict('list')

items_dic = {20: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 21: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3],
 22: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0],
 23: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6]}
```

but this does not include Pid in the list of values
Can someone explain why ?

Comment: Please, write the dataframe in proper format, not in picture.

Comment: I am sorry but I am fairly new to SO and I don't know how to do that

Comment: `drop=False` in `set_index` is what you need

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set parameter `drop=False` in [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), because default parameter `drop=False` move column to index:

```
cols = ["Length","Width","Height","Pid"]
items_dic = data[cols].set_index('Pid', drop=False).T.to_dict('list')

print (items_dic)

{20: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 20.0], 
 21: [4.6, 4.3, 4.3, 21.0], 
 22: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0, 22.0], 
 23: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 23.0]}
```

Answer (score 7):

Or use `dict(zip(...))`:

```
>>> cols = ["Length","Width","Height","Pid"]
>>> items_dic = dict(zip(df['Pid'],df[cols].values.tolist()))
>>> items_dic
{20: [4.8, 4.3, 4.3, 20.0], 21: [4.8, 4.3, 4.3, 21.0], 22: [6.0, 5.6, 9.0, 22.0], 23: [8.75, 5.6, 6.6, 23.0], 24: [6.0, 5.16, 6.6, 24.0]}
>>>
```